# How to add bash variables in psql while importing OSM data?

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, openstreetmap, psql

I'm trying to update the fields while importing the OSM data into the PostgreSQL DB using psql command on Linux.
I wanted to add the bash variables in the command., but I'm getting the error.

Command : `sudo docker exec dc2b20d450  su -l postgres -c /usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/psql --dbname=postgres --username=postgres --command=UPDATE planet_osm_point SET name_display=name WHERE "\""name:en"\"" IS NULL OR char_length(trim(both from "\""name:en"\""))<1 OR "\""name:en"\""=name;`

When I try to run the above command I'm receiving this error `` -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' `` 
I'm not getting how to fix this issue., Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Please format your code properly, so that we can see where one command ends and the next one starts. In the way you wrote it, the assignment to `localPsqlCommandLine` does not make sense. I suggest that you run your bash script with `set -x` enabled (for debugging), and that you paste it into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Comment: I'm not seeing where you are using bash variables (probably due to the decription having been edited?), but the problem seems to be rather clear: the query passed as argument to the --command parameter contains whitespace, so that argument needs to be enclosed in '...' or "...", or each whitespace escaped as `\ `

Comment: @HartmutHolzgraefe, Yes, I removed it.. But still I'm facing the same issue when I try to run the command.

Comment: Removed what? And did you try to enclose the actual query (the argument to --command) in single or double quotes yet?